# What is the right way to suppress Qt signals when values are explicitely set

Tags: qt, signals, qobject

I got a from QWidget derived class that holds three QSpinBoxes (e.g. coordinates). The `valueChanged()` signal is connected and is emitted in at least these three cases:

1. up/down button
2. manually entered number
3. `setValue()`

However, when using `setValue()`, I want to suppress the signal(s), since I don't want to have (three) signals. In my understanding, there are two ways to handle this:

1. `QObject::blockSignals()`
2. using a flag that indicates whether the values were explicitely set

Both variants work, but I think they are not straight-forward at all: For the first one, I generally block all signals AND I need to set `blockSignals(true)` for all underyling widgets (blockSignals doesn't block children QObjects in my application). For the second one, I need to query the flag in every update method AND the signals are raised although I don't need them.

Are there any general designing patterns that prevent such behavior? If not, what variant would you prefer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third option would be to subclass QSpinBox, implement desired functionality there, and used derived class instead of QSpinBox - this hides all associated complexity in derived class and allows you use it just like QSpinBox.

For example, following class

myQSpinBox.h

```
#ifndef MYQSPINBOX_H
#define MYQSPINBOX_H

#include <QSpinBox>

class myQSpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myQSpinBox(QWidget * parent = 0 );
protected:
    bool valueBeingSet;
public slots:
    void setValue (int val);
private slots:
    void On_valueChanged(int val);
signals:
    void valueChangedNotBySet(int val);
};

#endif // MYQSPINBOX_H
```

myQSpinBox.cpp

```
#include "myQSpinBox.h"

myQSpinBox::myQSpinBox(QWidget * parent)
        : QSpinBox(parent)
        , valueBeingSet(false)
{
    connect(this,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SLOT(On_valueChanged(int)));
}

void    myQSpinBox::setValue ( int val )
{
    valueBeingSet = true;
    QSpinBox::setValue(val);
    valueBeingSet = false;
}

void myQSpinBox::On_valueChanged(int val)
{
    if(!valueBeingSet)
        emit valueChangedNotBySet(val);
}
```

will emit `valueChangedNotBySet(int);` in cases 1. and 2., but not in case 3., keeping all QSpinBox functionality intact

Comment: Hey Ilya, thanks. You're absolutely right - that's the third (and so far cleanest) variant. However, I would need to reimplement (once) all kinds of widgets (the QSpinBox was just an example) - QLineEdit, QComboBox, QDoubleSpinBox, ... .

Comment: I'm not sure if QLineEdit needs to be reimplemented - since QLineEdit has signals textChanged(const QString & text) and textEdited(const QString & text) which allow to distinguish between types of edits. Same may apply to QComboBox...

Comment: That would work only when everything happens in the UI thread. When having chains of signal/slots connection across multiple thread, `valueBeingSet` will be set to `false` before the `valueChnaged` signal is emitted again (infinitely), because the event handler will be called asynchronously.

Comment: @mescalinum True, this example assumes single ui thread. However, I think it can be easily adapted to scenario you decribed by adding QWaitCondition member variable, and waiting on it after QSpinBox::setValue(val); and prior to setting valueBeingSet = false; (waking wait condition from On_valueChanged).